# ag grid - how to show side button (column)

Tags: ag-grid

I would like to know how to show the side button using AngularJs.
Currently it does not show on the page. I tried copy and paste some samples from the site but when it comes to my project it doesn't show.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the tool panel? tool panel comes in the enterprise version. Show your code in plunker else it is difficult to know where you are going wrong

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I just updated ag grid version and it working